# SlimFramework v3 - Same route with AND whithout final '/'

Tags: php, slim

I created a small application with [SlimFramework v3](http://www.slimframework.com/) and I am able to build a simple route like this:

```
// GET localhost/admin
$app->get('/admin', function(){
    # code here
});
```

My problem is that this work only for *localhost/admin* and not for *localhost/admin/* (with final backslash). Is there any option to use **ONE** route for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities

1. Specify an optional `/`

   ```
   $app->get('/admin[/]', function(){
       # code here
   });
   ```
2. Add middleware that redirects routes with an ending `/` to the url without that.

   ```
   use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface as Request;
   use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

   $app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
       $uri = $request->getUri();
       $path = $uri->getPath();
       if ($path != '/' && substr($path, -1) == '/') {
           // permanently redirect paths with a trailing slash
           // to their non-trailing counterpart
           $uri = $uri->withPath(substr($path, 0, -1));

           if($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
               return $response->withRedirect((string)$uri, 301);
           }
           else {
               return $next($request->withUri($uri), $response);
           }
       }

       return $next($request, $response);
   });
   ```

   (Source: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/route-patterns.html)